# Getting ID token from google sign-in

Tags: kotlin, oauth, google-oauth, http4k

I am trying to use http4k's built in oauth module to implement Google sign-in in my backend app.

Here is what I have so far:

```
val googleClientId = "<GoogleClientID>"
val googleClientSecret = "<GoogleClientSecret>"

// this is a test implementation of the OAuthPersistence interface, which should be
// implemented by application developers
val oAuthPersistence = InsecureCookieBasedOAuthPersistence("Google")

// pre-defined configuration exist for common OAuth providers
val oauthProvider = OAuthProvider.google(
  JavaHttpClient(),
  Credentials(googleClientId, googleClientSecret),
  Uri.of("http://localhost:9000/oauth/callback"),
  oAuthPersistence
)
val app: HttpHandler = routes(
  "/oauth" bind routes(
    "/" bind GET to oauthProvider.authFilter.then {
      val user = contextFn(it)
      Response(OK).body("authenticated!")
    },
    "/callback" bind GET to oauthProvider.callback
)
app.asServer(SunHttp(9000)).start()
```

This lets me go to `http://localhost:9000/oauth` and I can sign-in to my google account. Cool!

However, after the redirect, I go to the following function `contextFn`, which looks like this atm:

```
val transport = NetHttpTransport()
val jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()

val verifier = GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
  .setAudience(listOf(googleClientId))
  .build()

fun contextFn(request: Request): Principal {
  // TODO: get the id token somehow, but the request header only contains the following in cookie:
  // - GoogleCsrf
  // - GoogleAccessToken
  // - GoogleOriginalUri
  val idTokenString = ""

  val idToken: GoogleIdToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString)
  val payload: GoogleIdToken.Payload = idToken.payload

  // Print user identifier
  val userId: String = payload.subject
  println("User ID: $userId")

  // Get profile information from payload
  val email: String = payload.email
  val emailVerified: Boolean = payload.emailVerified
  val name = payload["name"]

  return GoogleUser(email)
}
```

How can i get the id token? Currently I am getting the access token from google.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this scope(**openid**)?
I am not sure listOf or addScope support in http4k
But it missed openid scope.

```
val oauthProvider = OAuthProvider.google(
  JavaHttpClient(),
  Credentials(googleClientId, googleClientSecret),
  Uri.of("http://localhost:9000/oauth/callback"),
  listOf("openidScope"),
  oAuthPersistence
)
oauthProvider.addScope('openid');
```